# Letting the computer decide the outcome

Tags: algorithms

I have exactly no knowledge of programming. I want to design/develop/etc a video game I've been wanting to do and part of this is a crafting system similar to what Skyrim has.

Let's say we are working on making an edible food or drink. I want the character to be able to mix ANY ingredient to create a food or drink or even potion. But I don't want there to necessarily be a set outcome. I want the computer to be able to read the information of several ingredients and let the computer decide what the effects of the created product will be.

For example: The player would grab several totally random seemingly unrelated ingredients, and when mixing the ingredients to create a usable object the computer would then read those things and decide the effects. Once the potion/food/drink/poison is created it is a learned recipe.

What would the code for that even look like?

Comment: If you dont want a set outcome for the same input, simply generate random output

Comment: Generating random output on a computer is anything but "simple". We work very hard to make sure our computers behave deterministically.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pseudorandom numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) to randomize those elements.